# Nitric acid plus Hydroiodic acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, redox

Why $\ce{I2}$ is formed when $\ce{HI}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ are reacted?

I know that $\ce{HI}$ is more acidic than $\ce{HNO3}$ so nitric acid will accept protons from $\ce{HI}$, so $\ce{I-}$ (iodide ion ) should be formed and nitric acid on accepting proton would form $\ce{H2NO3+}$ but that is not formed why?

[image: iodination of alkane]

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/600/why-is-nitric-acid-such-a-strong-oxidizing-agent

Comment: This is not about acidic strength and protons at all. This is a redox reaction.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  in an weak acid strong acid reaction products are formed such that weak acid gets proton and strong acid looses proton but in redox reaction what is rule of thumb if reduction potentials are not known?

Comment: Nobody remembers the exact potentials, but you are expected to know that $\ce{HNO3}$ is a pretty strong oxidant, while $\ce I$ is an element with relatively low electronegativity (for a non-metal, that is). That should suffice.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I2 formed will react with HNO3 to form hio3 and as seen in image in question this Hio3 will again produce I2 so where does overall reaction leads us to?

Comment: That depends on how much $\ce{HI}$ do you have.

Comment: @IvanNeretin can you please explain why image says iodination is reversible?

Comment: Because it is reversible; what's unclear about that? The C-I bond is not particularly strong and snaps easily.

Comment: @IvanNeretin could you please answer this: chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57714/selectivity-of-catalysts  and thanks for above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44481/discussion-between-jm97-and-ivan-neretin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nitrate is a strong oxidant which oxidizes the iodide to iodine.

$$\ce{NO_3^- + 2I^- + 2H^+\rightarrow NO_2^- + I_2 \uparrow + H2O}$$

Note that the oxidation number of the nitrogen atom in $\ce{NO3-}$ is $+V$ and in $\ce{NO2-}$ it's $+III$, so over all, we have a reduction equation of:

$$\ce{NO_3^- + 2e^- + 2H^+\rightarrow NO_2^- + H2O}$$

On the oxidation side we want to form $\ce{I_2}$ out of $\ce{I^-}$, so the oxidation equation is:

$$\ce{2I^- \rightarrow I_2 + 2e^-}$$

Comment: Actually, I don't believe it will stop at I2. Also, pay attention to the formatting and use \ce{}.

Comment: In parts it will react further, but test it and you'll see, that a violet vapour ($\ce{I2}$) comes out of the beaker, so you definitely form iodine.

Comment: No, iodine is oxidized only by concentrated (fuming) nitric acid.

Comment: Well, I have made a different experience during my internship. When adding an iodide solution to an unknown, nitrate-containing substance violet vapors came out of my beaker, thus iodide was definitely oxidized to iodine. And that unknown solution was definitely not fuming $\ce{HNO3}$.

Comment: @Chwebo I mean that elemental iodine is difficult to oxidize with diluted nitric acid. Iodide ions are on the other hand easily oxidized.

Comment: @vapid Oh okay, then I misunderstood you. I've just briefly looked at my table works and yes to oxidize iodine further you would need at least fuming $\ce{HNO3}$. For the questioner therefore only elemental iodine remains.

Comment: Agreed. Diluted $\ce{HNO3}$ will give $\ce{I2}$, concentrated acid will push further.