# Can we use (KBr + H2SO4) instead of (NaBr +H2SO4) in reaction with alcohol to generate alkyl bromide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I have read somewhere that $\ce{H2SO4}$ is used to generate $\ce{HBr},$ and at the other place it is written that it is there to protonate the hydroxyl group. Which fact should I believe ?

Comment: No problem with that. But sometimes HBr might react with H2SO4. See my answer to the question here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77198/why-do-we-need-sulfuric-acid-in-creating-alkyl-bromide-and-not-in-creating-alkyl?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use $\ce{KBr + H2SO4}$ instead of $\ce{NaBr + H2SO4}$ because they both give $\ce{HBr}$ which is used in the preparation of alkyl bromide.
The basic reaction is as follows:
$$\ce{ROH + HBr -> RBr + H2O}$$
The above-mentioned compounds $\ce{NaBr}$ and $\ce{KBr}$ are used only for the preparation of $\ce{HBr}$.

Comment: You haven't answered the main question in the body. Try to add that too.

Answer (score 0):

H2SO4 is used to protonate the OH group and form OH2+ group which is a good leaving group.

OH2+ leaves the substrate and forms a carbocation.

Then (Br-) anion attacks on the carbocation so formed.

HBr NaBr KBr all liberate (Br-) anion in the solvent.

So all will give the same product.

H2SO4 has the task to generate H+ that protonates the alcohol.

Your book might have tried to explain it like H2SO4 first forms HBr. Ultimately HBr will dissosiate to give H+ which does the protonation.

Rest over to you. You may believe both or none!